# VBA code that changes zoom level based on text/object in sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, zooming

All,

I've been looking for VBA code that achieves the following:

1. Sets zoom to 80% for worksheets that contain a certain key word
2. Sets zoom to 60% for worksheets that contain a picture
3. Sets zoom to 85% for worksheets that contain a different key word

Here is the code that I have been trying to manipulate to suit this particular challenge, with my non-code comments indicating what I'd like to change:

```
Sub ZoomSheets() 
   Dim ws As Worksheet  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    For Each ws *with a picture* In Worksheets 
        ws.Activate
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 60
    Next
    For Each ws *that contains X text* In Worksheets 
        ws.Activate
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
    Next
    For Each ws *that contains Y text* In Worksheets 
        ws.Activate
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

For a certain deliverable at my job, the manager prefers certain sheets within an excel workbook to be at different zoom levels depending on what the sheet contains: 60% if there is a picture, 85% if it says "Y" at the top and 80% if it says "X" at the top.  I've been able to find VBA code that sets a uniform zoom across all sheets, but I am looking for help writing code that is a little more flexible and allows me to vary the zoom depending on what the sheet contains.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ZoomSheets()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim checkRng As String: checkRng = "A1:ZZ999"
    Dim picture As Variant
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        With ws.Range(checkRng)
            If Not .Find("epic", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                ws.Activate
                ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
            ElseIf Not .Find("poggers", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                ws.Activate
                ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
            Else
                For Each picture In ws.Pictures
                    If picture.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
                        ws.Activate
                        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End With
    
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Manuel, thanks for helping me resolve this issue. I realized I had some more conditions, and I was able to modify the code by adding more elseifs. Appreciate it!

Comment: No worries, happy it worked for you. Would you mind marking my answer correct if it helped? Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing! Your answer was very helpful1